# Django CSRF framework ignoring session cookie domain

Tags: python, django, cookies

I'm using the [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) setting in Django to specify that it store all my app's cookie's under the "mysite.com" domain. However, after testing in Firefox/Chrome, I'm finding that even though most cookies are now using the correct domain, Django is still storing the "csrftoken" cookie under the full hostname (e.g. "sub.mysite.com").

Does this look like a bug in Django, or should the CSRF framework explicitly ignore my custom SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSRF is not tied to the session and has its own setting for the cookie domain [`CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-domain).